# touch image zooming inside a viewpager in android

Tags: android

hello i have a grid view of images while on item click images are viewed in a viewpager , this is working fine but i need to make the images zoomable in the pager here is my code

ImageAdapter.java

```
    import com.netvariant.qareeboon.android.R;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }


        // References to our images in res > drawable
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.bg_logo, R.drawable.three,
                R.drawable.four, R.drawable.two,
                R.drawable.one, R.drawable.btn_about,

        };
    }
```

ImagePagerAdapter.java

```
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

ImageViewPager.java

```
package com.netvariant.android.qareeboon;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.netvariant.qareeboon.android.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewPager extends Activity {
    // Declare Variable
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the ViewPager
        setTitle("ViewPager");
        // Get the view from view_pager.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

        // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
        Intent p = getIntent();
        position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");

        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        // Retrieve all the images
        for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            images.add(imageView);
        }

        // Set the images into ViewPager
        ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
        ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
        // Show images following the position
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.netvariant.android.qareeboon;
import com.netvariant.qareeboon.android.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.view.View;

public class InfoGraphicActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set title for the GridView
        setTitle("GridView");
        // Get the view from grid_view.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

        // Set the images from ImageAdapter.java to GridView
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
       // ViewPager viewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        // Listening to GridView item click
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Launch ImageViewPager.java on selecting GridView Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageViewPager.class);

                // Send the click position to ImageViewPager.java using intent
                i.putExtra("id", position);

                // Start ImageViewPager
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    // Not using options menu for this tutorial
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.info_graphic, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Chris Bane's PhotoView in place of ImageView

Comment: thank you very much photoview is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public MyPagerAdapter mypager;
public int currentimageindex;
public Context context;
private ViewPager pager;
public static  int position; 
int pics[];
String[] stringArray;


public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
}

public MyPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] pics, String[] stringArra) {
    this.pics = pics;
    this.context = context;
    stringArray = stringArra;
}

public MyPagerAdapter(Context Context, String[] stringArra) {
    this.context = context;
    stringArray = stringArra;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 13;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    // return view == ((ImageView) object);
    return view == ((View) object);

}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textnimage, null);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
    image.setImageResource(pics[position]);


    System.out.println("===position=== " +position);
    currentimageindex = position ;
    //System.out.println("end of 1 adapter");
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, ImageWithDetail.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent2.putExtra("currentimageindex", currentimageindex);
            context.startActivity(intent2);



        }
    });

    TextView txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image_text);
    txt.setText(stringArray[position]);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ((ViewGroup) collection).addView(layout, layoutParams);

    return layout;
}



public void setMypager(MyPagerAdapter mypager) {
    this.mypager = mypager;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}





public int getCurrentimageindex() {
    return currentimageindex;
}

public void setCurrentimageindex(int currentimageindex) {
    this.currentimageindex = currentimageindex;
}

}
```